# In Ada, is there a way to make an enumeration type act like a modulus type -- to wrap to 0 after the last of it's range?

Tags: math, enums, ada

I am re-writing an encryption/compression library and it seems like it is getting to be a lot of processing per bytes processed.  I would prefer to use an enumeration type when choosing which of several limited ways the encryption can go (the proper way), but when those paths become cyclical, I have to add extra code to test for type'last and type'first.  I can always just write such a condition in for the type, or assign the addition/subtraction operator on the type a function to wrap around the result, but that is more code and processing that will add up quickly when it has to run every eight bytes along with everything else.  Is there a way to make the operation about as efficient as if it were a simple "mod" type, like

```
type Modular is mod 64 ....;
for ......;
pragma ....;
type Frequency_Counter is array(Modular) of Long_Integer;
Head : Modular := (others => 0);
Freq : Frequency_Counter(Size) := (others => 0);
Encryption_Label : Modular := Hash3;
Block_Sample : Modular := Hash5;
...
Hash3 := Hash3 + 1;
Freq (Hash3):= Freq(Hash3) + 1; -- Here is where my made-on-the-fly example is focused
```

I think I can make the whole algorithm more efficient and use enumeration types if I can just get the enumeration type to do math in the processor in the same number of cycles as with a mod type math.  I have gotten a little creative in thinking of a way, but they were too obviously not right for me to use any of them as an example.  The only thing I can think might be possible exceeds my skill, and that is making a procedure using inline ASM (gas assembly language syntax) to make the operation very direct to the processor.

PS: I know this is a minor gain, alone. Any gain is appropriate for the application.

Comment: Be careful when rewriting encryption libraries.  Some inefficiencies are intentional in order to mitigate side channel attacks.  That being said, the fancy way to improve performance of encryption is to leverage the [AES Instruction Set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AES_instruction_set).  This tends to provide a 5X or higher performance boost.

Comment: I appreciate the warning, though I am humbled because I am not educated enough in side channel attacks to prevent them, however, I do think the risk is low since no keys are stored directly in the library -- they are converted directly upon input to a buffered block of interpreted values, which is used in at least two of the cyclical operations.  The usage platforms don't all support the AES Instruction Set.  Thanks for the help :)

Comment: That's insufficient to protect against timing attacks.  That said, many such attacks become less concerning when encryption is client-side rather than server-side.  Another concern would be inadvertently weakening the encryption.  This cannot be easily detected via things like unit tests; a weakened form of AES will still be fully compatible with a proper implementation of AES (e.g., a broken RNG).

Comment: Your input has helped me much.  I have made it a part of my project to process blanks and random numbers irrespective of the key length at one or two parts.  I am still naive about such attacks, but I think I grasp how the timing could be tested repeatedly with various keys and the cycles of input/output tracked to provide an abstract of the encryption process.  While the application is intended to be client side, there is no reason that it couldn't be used on a server someday, therefore I will aim for same number of cycles/timing regardless of input/key.  Thanks, again.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not sure that it’ll make much difference!

Given this

```ada
package Cyclic is

   type Enum is (A, B, C, D, E);
   type Modular is mod 5;

   function Next_Enum (En : Enum) return Enum is
     (if En = Enum'Last then Enum'First else Enum'Succ (En))                                --'
   with Inline_Always;

end Cyclic;
```

and

```ada
with Cyclic; use Cyclic;
procedure Cyclic_Use (N : Natural; E : in out Enum; M : in out Modular) is
begin

   begin
      for J in 1 .. N loop
         E := Next_Enum (E);
      end loop;
   end;

   begin
      for J in 1 .. N loop
         M := M + 1;
      end loop;
   end;

end Cyclic_Use;
```

and compiling using GCC 5.2.0 with -O3 (`gnatmake -O3 -c -u -f cyclic_use.adb -cargs -S`), the x86_64 assembler generated for the two loops is

(enumeration)

```
L3:
        leal    1(%rsi), %ecx
        addl    $1, %eax
        cmpb    $4, %sil
        cmove   %r8d, %ecx
        cmpl    %eax, %edi
        movl    %ecx, %esi
        jne     L3
```

(modular)

```
L4:
        leal    -4(%rdx), %ecx
        addl    $1, %eax
        cmpb    $3, %dl
        leal    1(%rdx), %r8d
        movl    %ecx, %edx
        cmovle  %r8d, %edx
        cmpl    %eax, %edi
        jne     L4
```

I don’t pretend to know x86_64 assembler, and I don’t know why the enumeration version compares against 4 while the modular version compares against 3, but these look very similar to me! but the enumeration version is one instruction shorter ...

Comment: I didn't realize that I could use GCC to generate ASM.  With a reference manual of ASM and this output, I should be able to figure this out.  I am actually a bit surprised to see that the enum ASM is actually shorter than the modular.  As I remember from studying ASM fifteen years ago, each instruction (with exception to certain macros) represents one instruction call to the processor and thus relevant cycles used.  For this reason, my error has been detected and the reduction of generated code resolved, so I am marking this the answer...  Thanks!

Comment: GCC always (well, I think so ...) generates assembler. It’s just that it’s normally thrown away, leaving you with the object code. `-S` keeps it.